# Typescript class.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

Creating an Angular2 app, I am facing the following problem, when calling the constructor of another class inside the constructor of first class.

First Class code

```
import SecondClass from './second-class'

export class FirstClass {
    someVar:string;
    secondClass:SecondClass;

    constructor(firstClass?: FirstClass) {
        someVar='test';
        secondClass= new SecondClass;
    }
}
```

Second Class code:

```
export class SecondClass {
    someOtherVar:string;

    constructor(secondClass?:SecondClass) {
        someOtherVar='test';
    }
}
```

Would give me the error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: second_class_1.default is not a constructor

Content of ./second-class

```
System.register([], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var SecondClass;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            SecondClass = (function () {
                function SecondClass(secondClass) {
                    this.someOtherVar='test';
                }
                return SecondClass;
            }());
            exports_1("SecondClass", SecondClass);
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=second-class.js.map
```

This is the compiled output from Typescript compiler

Comment: Post content of `./second-class`.

Comment: `default` is a [javascript reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords).

Comment: Possible cyclic error for SecondClass

Comment: I reverted your edit because it invalidates the answers and makes the question completely unhelpful for anyone coming along.

Answer (score 15):

Error message implies that you used named export (`export class SecondClass {}`) in `./second-class` (not default). So it means that your import should looks something like

```
import {SecondClass} from './second-class'
```

Comment: Thanks. Modified the code but still getting error like ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: second_class_1.SecondClass is not a constructor

Comment: Can you post contents of the './second-class'? (TypeScript, not transpiled).

Comment: I have it in my question just below the FirstClass code.

Answer (score 6):

There are some errors in the code :

- missing `{}` from import
- missing `()` from calling the constructor
- missing `this` from accessing Class members

First Class code

```
import {SecondClass} from './second-class'

export class FirstClass {
    someVar:string;
    secondClass:SecondClass;

    constructor(firstClass?: FirstClass) {
        this.someVar='test';
        this.secondClass= new SecondClass();
    }
}
```

Second Class code:

```
export class SecondClass {
    someOtherVar:string;

    constructor(secondClass?:SecondClass) {
        this.someOtherVar='test';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. These were typos when typing the question. The code, without these errors is giving said error.

Answer (score 0):

this is too late, but I just got the same error right now. Solution is export `SecondClass` as default so Second Class code will be:

```
export default class SecondClass {
    someOtherVar:string;

    constructor(secondClass?:SecondClass) {
        this.someOtherVar='test';
    }
}
```

and import in other class with `import SecondClass from './second-class'`